# Tkinter: create a function to flash images

Tags: python, tkinter

Right now I’ve four images in my app and I need for all them to blink five times and then to stay put in the frame for five seconds one after another from the first to the fourth. To do so I’m trying to create a function like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image, ImageGrab 

class Blinking(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs) 

        self.img_1_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('img_1.png'))
        self.img_2_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('img_2.png'))
        self.img_3_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('img_3.png'))
        self.img_4_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('img_4.png'))

        self.img_1_label = tk.Label(self, image=self.img_1_img, relief="solid")
        self.img_1_label.pack(padx=50, side='left', anchor='w')

        self.img_2_label = tk.Label(self, image=self.img_2_img, relief="solid")
        self.img_2_label.pack(padx=50, side='left', anchor='w')

        self.img_3_label = tk.Label(self, image=self.img_3_img, relief="solid")
        self.img_3_label.pack(padx=50, side='left', anchor='w')

        self.img_4_label = tk.Label(self, image=self.img_4_img, relief="solid")
        self.img_4_label.pack(padx=50, side='left', anchor='w')

        self.blink_img(self.img_1_label)      

    def blink_img(self, img):
        for i in range(3):
            i +=1
            if i % 5 != 0:
                self.img.after(500, self.blink_img)
                self.img.after(1000, self.blink_img) 
            else:
                # the image stay in the frame for five seconds, I print() something and then the next image start to blink


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Blinking(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

But I’m getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Blinking' object has no attribute 'img'
```

It’s my first time trying to create a function like this. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change `self.img.after` to `img.after` to remove the error. Also I suspect that there is something very wrong with your `blink_img` function as you are calling `.after` from a for loop. To read more about `.after`, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/459131/11106801)

Comment: Thanks! Followed your advice and it worked, but now I'm getting this error : `TypeError: blink_img() missing 1 required positional argument: 'img`

Comment: Move  `i += 1` to the bottom outside of the `if/else` statement. will solve the problem.